# What is the best practice to align a header a button, text and right component in UI using react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I need to align the Back button and Text and Right element in my header section.

I am using react-native-elements component to align but the styles Which I gave not worked for all text. If the text is small it not working as expected.Also If I try line spacing for the text LIST it not shows space in it. Refer the expo for sample code(here I not added line spacing) and refer the attachment.

https://snack.expo.io/@niph/grounded-watermelon

My question what **is the best practice to achieve** this. I have added marginLeft values as negative.

[image]

Comment: are you aligning all the components to be on the same line?

Comment: No above screen shot is which I needed. But my code has the margin values as -150 to align the text to left. I think it is not a good approach to add the negative margin values.

Answer (score 0):

You have put your `title name` under the `left button` in the header. This eliminates the need to use `centerComponent`.
And you have to use `outerContainerStyles` to change the height of the **header**. Then, adjust the area using flex values and use `alignSelf` to reposition only text.

**Usage**  If you want to experience this, look at [my example](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/custom-header-in-react-native-elements).

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (   <Header
        outerContainerStyles={{paddingTop: 0, height:130}}
        backgroundColor='green'
        leftComponent = {
          <View style={{flexDirection:"row",flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { .5 }>
            <Entypo name = {'chevron-thin-left'} size ={30} style = {{ color:'white'}}></Entypo>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={{fontSize:30, color:'white',alignSelf:"flex-end"}}>NAMES</Text>
        </View>
         }
        // centerComponent = {<Text style={{fontSize:30, color:'white', flexDirection:'row'}}>NAMES</Text>}
        rightComponent = {<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { .5 } style={{flex:1,marginTop:20}}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize:14, color:'white',textDecorationLine:'underline'}}>LIST</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>}
          />
    );
  }
}
```

**Enabled screen**

[image: custom screenheader]

Comment: I not need the header labels in the same line. I need like the image which I attached in my question. Refer this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ggSr.png. Need to be same in all devices.

Comment: @sejn If my answer was helpful, would you please check and select the 'V' and arrow?

Comment: It does not work correctly if the text length is too large https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTjO5.png.  Refer https://snack.expo.io/@niph/headerwith-large-text